# Tag links in Meta have visited colors

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Tags don't usually have visited colors (a:visited) on the SE network but on UX Meta they do (but not UX's main site). You can see this below; the visited [specific-question](/questions/tagged/specific-question) tag has differently colored text compared to the non-visited text. You can click the [specific-question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/specific-question) and click back to see the effect yourself

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for bringing this up. I have fixed the CSS so that tags always remain the same color - visited or not. It will be live in the next meta build (> `rev 2014.10.17.1950`).